# shoulda matchers should validate_uniqueness_of failing with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I have 3 models, user, game, and player. There's basically a many to many relationship between users and games, with players as the join table, except players have other info so it has its own model.

A player needs a unique combo of game id and user id, so I tried to say in player:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :game_id
```

and then in my spec, I said (using shoulda matchers):

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id).scoped_to(:game_id)}
```

here are the relationships the player defines:

```
belongs_to :game, :inverse_of => :players
belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :players
```

yet I'm getting an ActiveRecord::statementinvalid error on that spec

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'game_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `players` ETC...
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a [known issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/194). It gives this error if the scoped field is dependent on the model and is also set to `:null => false`.

Also, do have a look at [rails Column cannot be null:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955953/rails-column-cannot-be-null)

Comment: Update: this will be fixed in v 2.7. See: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/commit/e3493811865a42b4bebcf0d3001333b9d4cb5208

Answer (score 9):

While this is a known issue, there is a way around it.

If you first create a record and then test the uniqueness validation, it will work.

So, instead of simply writing

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id) }
```

You can write

```
it do
  FactoryGirl.create(:player)
  should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id)
end
```

And the uniqueness validation spec will work.

Reference: http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/frames

Comment: or `it { expect(create(:label)).to validate_uniqueness_of(:value).scoped_to(:question_id) }` to get everything on one smooth line with rspec3 syntax.

Answer (score 3):

For people having this issue today here is a newer solution.

Add a subject so that the tests have a record with values.

Also, note the newer RSpec syntax.

```
    subject { create(:player) }

    it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id).scoped_to(:game_id)}
```

Check out [the file on github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/validate_uniqueness_of_matcher.rb#L50) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the issue and solutions mentioned in the official source code caveat [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/validate_uniqueness_of_matcher.rb)

One solution is:

```
describe Player do
  describe "validations" do
    it do
      expect(Player.new(game_id: 1)).
        to validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id).
        scoped_to(:game_id)
    end
  end
end
```