# How to use shoulda-matcher to test uniqueness of one foreign key scoped to the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, testing, rspec

I know that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268146/shoulda-matchers-should-validate-uniqueness-of-failing-with-scope) exists, but the answers didn't help me.

Working with the Participant Model, which

```
belongs_to :game
belongs_to :team
```

The shoulda-matcher code that I need to work is

```
it {should validate_uniqueness_of(:team).scoped_to(:game)
```

The code in my Participant Model is

```
validates :team, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :game}
```

I have tried to follow the answers at the above question and the solutions on the [git hub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/682#issuecomment-151715507) itself for this known issue, and gotten no luck.

If I just leave it 'clean' I get this error:

```
 Failure/Error: it {should validate_uniqueness_of(:team).scoped_to(:game)}

 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
   Team(#70267561823460) expected, got String(#70267552833620)
```

To complicate things just a little, Team `belongs_to :division`

I'm using rspec and rails 5.  Is there an answer within shoulda-matchers is the question?

To answer the first question - I haven't tried it in the console yet - I was avoiding that as this is a known issue with shoulda I just can't get any of the reported workarounds to work.

Comment: Hi - can you please include a little more of your code? eg the validates-uniqueness-of line in your model? also the part of your spec where you create the other Participant (that your new one is supposed to clash with) :) Also - have you literally tried this in the console/browser to see if it works there too?